# Getting Error message in MAC OS X terminal

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

```
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/developer/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/developer/.rvm/bin:/Users/developer/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/developer/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/tools': not a valid identifier
```

Am getting above error message after terminal successfully launched .

I installed cordova 3.1.0  and to add path to $PATH i used the following code

```
$ echo 'export PATH = /usr/local/bin/:$PATH'>>~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont make spaces around the `=`

```
$ echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH'>>~/.bash_profile
```

when you get the same error all the time you open a terminal edit the `.bash_profile` file in your home-directory and delete the whitespaces around the `=` at the last line.

lg

fastrde

Comment: Go to the home dir and open the file. "cd $HOME" and then "vi .bash_profile"

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with Android ADT.  I'd (stupidly) called the SDK folder 'Android SDK', so I had to manually edit .bash_profile using vi to add a backslash before the space (e.g. ../HOME/Android\ SDK/Tools/).